# How to render a option of select element - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote this function to make a tree options.

```
makeTreeOption(tree) {
    let ouput = `<optgroup label="${tree.title}">`;
    if (tree['children']) {
      tree.children.forEach(children => {
        if (children['children']) {
          ouput += this.makeTreeOption(children);
        } else {
          ouput += `<option>${children.title}</option>`;
        }
      });
    }
    ouput += `</optgroup>`;
    return ouput;
  }
```

but when I want to render it:

```
  <select>
       {this.makeTreeOption(data)}
  </select>
```

it returns this:

[image]

Comment: You would need `<select dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:makeTree() }}>` but a better way to do this would be to use a component and then push it into an array

Comment: Like SimonR demonstrates, compose JSX, not HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/4sqve2np/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than building a string you need the `makeTreeOption` method to return JSX. Something like:

```
function makeTreeOption(tree) {
    return <optgroup /*...optgroup props */>{
        tree.children.map(
            child => child.children
                ? makeTreeOption(child)
                : <option /* ...option props */>{ child.title }</option>
        )
    }</optgroup>
}
```